# Nested Facets to Aggregation conversion in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, facet

I have below es query which I need to migrate from 1.5 to 5.5
I understand that I need to convert facets to aggregation. However, in the below example, there is nested query & facet_filter both involved..
Basically I want to figure out the count of each field_val in all the search documents, where the corresponding field_name of the nested document is "rg"

```
"facets": {
    "rg_facet": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "profile.field_val",
            "size": 100
        },
        "nested": "profile",
        "facet_filter": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [
                    {
                        "term": {
                            "profile.field_name": "rg"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

profile is nested field. A typical document looks like below

```
{
  "field1" : "val1",
  ....
  "profile" : [
        {
          "field_val": "1705209",
          "field_name": "a_0"
        },
        {
          "field_val": "Batch 14",
          "field_name": "a_2"
        },
        {
          "field_val": "Delhi",
          "field_name": "rg"
        }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "profile_agg": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "profile"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "rg_filter": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "profile.field_name": "rg"
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "field_vals": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "profile.field_val", 
                "size": 100
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

See [nested aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-nested-aggregation.html), [filter aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html), and [terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html)